# Colored tables with booktabs, makecell and cellspace

Tags: tables, color, booktabs, makecell, cellspace

While experimenting with different table-packages, I realised, that each package basically stands for itself and often lacks in compatibility with other great packages.

So I tried to create a table in the style of the `booktabs`-package (only horizontal lines), but with the functionality of the `makecell`-package (`\thead`, `\makegapedcells`, ...) and the possibility to color the rows (which is not very intuitive with `booktabs`, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177202/booktabs-and-row-color).)

I made a little comparison between different table-configurations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[column=Q]{cellspace}    % changed to Q for simultaneous use of siunitx

\newcommand{\tableComment}[2]{
    \begin{tabular}{m{4.5cm}}
        #1\\[5pt]#2
    \end{tabular}}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cc}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\renewcommand{\cellrotangle}{90}

\newcommand{\TopRule}{\Xhline{1pt}}
\newcommand{\MidRule}{\Xhline{.5pt}}
\newcommand{\BottomRule}{\Xhline{1pt}}


\begin{document}

\tableComment{1: Standard Lines, Head with \texttt{makecell}, no additional spacing}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \hline
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{2: Standard Lines, Head with \texttt{makecell}, spacing with \texttt{cellspace}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\hline
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \hline
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{3: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{makecell}, spacing with \texttt{cellspace}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}\\

\tableComment{4: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{thead}, spacing with \texttt{makegapedcells}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \thead{My Head} & \thead{My second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{5: Lines with \texttt{booktabs}, Head with \texttt{makecell}, spacing with \texttt{booktabs}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \midrule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{6: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{thead}, spacing with \texttt{cellspace}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \thead{My Head} & \thead{My second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}

\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont second}
\tableComment{7: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{callspace} }
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{8: Lines with \texttt{booktabs}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{booktabs}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\\midrule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{9: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{makegapedcells}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

With the following result:
[image: Different Table Configurations]

As you can see, in almost every combination of packages there are some difficulties (or it simply doesn't look good). My favourites are Versions 3 and 6.

But I found no solutions for rotated cells, or by using `\makegapedcells`

How would you create colored tables in booktabs-style? (And what does the `booktabs`-package actually do except introducing new horizontal lines and changing the vertical space?). And why does `\makegapedcells` delete all colors except inside the `\thead`?

Comment: What about `\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\itshape\cellcolor{gray!40}}
\tableComment{10: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{cellspace}, color with \texttt{cellcolor}}
{
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        %\rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}` as an alternative for colored cells with rotated text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to vertical spacing in cells, the winner is … (drum roll) … `cellspace`, provided you use it the correct way – you simply forgot to  specify the values of the minimal spacing at the top and bottom of cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[column=Q]{cellspace} % changed to Q for simultaneous use of siunitx
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}

\newcommand{\tableComment}[2]{
    \begin{tabular}{m{4.5cm}}
        #1\\[5pt]#2
    \end{tabular}}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cc}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\renewcommand{\cellrotangle}{90}

\newcommand{\TopRule}{\Xhline{1pt}}
\newcommand{\MidRule}{\Xhline{.5pt}}
\newcommand{\BottomRule}{\Xhline{1pt}}


\begin{document}

\tableComment{1: Standard Lines, Head with \texttt{makecell}, no additional spacing}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \hline
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{2: Standard Lines, Head with \texttt{makecell}, spacing with \texttt{\color{red}cellspace}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\hline
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \hline
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{3: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{makecell}, spacing with \texttt{\color{red}cellspace}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}\\

\tableComment{4: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{thead}, spacing with \texttt{makegapedcells}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \thead{My Head} & \thead{My second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{5: Lines with \texttt{booktabs}, Head with \texttt{makecell}, spacing with \texttt{booktabs}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        My Head & \makecell{My second\\ Head} \\ \midrule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{6: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{thead}, spacing with \texttt{\color{red}cellspace}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \thead{My Head} & \thead{My second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}

\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont second}
\tableComment{7: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{\color{red}cellspace} }
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{QlQl}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{8: Lines with \texttt{booktabs}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{booktabs}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\\midrule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\tableComment{9: Lines with \texttt{Xhline}, Head with \texttt{rothead}, spacing with \texttt{makegapedcells}}
{
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\TopRule
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        \rothead{My\\Head} & \rothead{My\\second\\ Head} \\ \MidRule
        some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
        foo & bar \\ \BottomRule
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `cellspace` may give uneven height of the rows, depending on cell content. With all the packages, you will experience the problem that the rules disappear in browser, because colour overwrites them.

The package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) is actually the only package that I have found that overcomes most of the problems.

Another possibility is to cancel all space between cells in the table (`\tabcolsep{0pt}` `arraystretch > 1` ) and then add spacing between columns with narrow columns and between rows with a combination of heavy, horizontal rules with the same colour as the row and (eventually) a narrow, black `arrayrulesep`.

You then imitate the old way of typesetting tabulars when the typesetter spaced out columns and rows using struts of lead.

[I plan to give some examples, but I ran into some side effects of a command and need first to ask a question!]

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix` (≥ 5.6) and `booktabs`, you have directly the following result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[cell-space-limits=1pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!40}{1} 
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
\Body
  \toprule
  My Head & \Block{}<\rotate>{My second\\ Head} \\ 
  \midrule
  some content & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
  foo & bar \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

The commands `\toprule`, `midrule` and `\bottomrule` are provided by `booktabs`; `\Block` and `\rotate` are provided by `nicematrix`. The keywords `\CodeBefore` and `\Body` and the commands within (`\rowcolor` and `\rowcolors`) are provided by `nicematrix`. The package `colortbl` is not loaded. It could have been loaded with the same result.