# How to prevent overflow of row/cell colors in booktabs?

Tags: tables, color, booktabs, rowcolor, cellcolor

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5365/98645) you know how to easily create rows with background colors. This also works for `booktabs`.

**Edit:** This is how it looks by default with `\begin{tabular}{lccc}`:
[image: with padding]

But we want to change that…
So there is a problem if you intend to use `@{}`.
`@{}` makes the table a little smaller at the left and right side and it looks very professional.

Usually…
Because with colored rows, it does not, because they (horizontally) "overflow" the table.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table} \centering
        \rowcolors{1}{white}{yellow}
        
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l ccc@{}}
            & Head & Head & Head \\
            \cmidrule{1-4}
            line 1 & Y & N & Y \\
            line 2 & Y & N & Y \\
            line 3 & Y & N & Y \\
            line 4 & Y & N & Y \\
            \rowcolor{red}
            line 5 & Y & N & Y \\
            \cellcolor{green}%
            line 6 & Y & N & 
            \cellcolor{green}%
            Y \\
            \cmidrule{1-4}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: exaggerated example with green, yellow an red rows]

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry for the dupe, just found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177285/98645), which looks awfully complicated (and maybe there are better solutions?), but here it is adjusted to my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table} \centering
        \rowcolors{1}{white}{yellow}
        
        \begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}l ccc<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}
            & Head & Head & Head \\
            \cmidrule{1-4}
            line 1 & Y & N & Y \\
            line 2 & Y & N & Y \\
            line 3 & Y & N & Y \\
            line 4 & Y & N & Y \\
            \rowcolor{red}
            line 5 & Y & N & Y \\
            \cellcolor{green}%
            line 6 & Y & N & 
            \cellcolor{green}%
            Y \\
            \cmidrule{1-4}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: works now]

Comment: the simpler version is just to go with the flow and allow colortbl to add the column padding either side, so just use `{lccc}`  it is the `@{}` that make things tricky. That usually looks better anyway rather than have the `line` text flush to the edge of the colour panel.

Comment: Hmm added that to the question for comparison. And I think, hmm. Naw. Depends on the style you like and maybe even on the content.